# Get value of last option of a drop down?

Tags: javascript, html

I have dropdown menu..which is dynamic.. How can get value of the last item in that drop down (using jquery is also acceptable)

Comment: What do you mean by "drop down menu"? Are you using JavaScript to create a drop down menu effect? If so, can you please tell us what script you are using.

Comment: +1 - I totally agree with you @TobiasCohen: "what did you try? what did you get? what did you expect to get?"

Answer (score 83, accepted):

With jQuery it's super easy:

```
var lastValue = $('#idOfSelect option:last-child').val();
```

With plain Javascript it's not much worse:

```
var theSelect = document.getElementById('idOfSelect');
var lastValue = theSelect.options[theSelect.options.length - 1].value;
```

Answer (score 10):

With jQuery:

```
$('select option:last').val()
```

Of course you should use a proper ID to address the `select` element.

If you mean "menu" it terms of a list, you can do it similar:

```
// gives the text inside the last <li> element
$('#menu li:last').text()

// gives you the attribute 'some_attribute' of the last <li> element
$('#menu li:last').attr('some_attribute')
```

The key here is to use the `:last` selector.

Comment: $('select option:last').val()
 its not working...
answer given by pointy is working..
var lastValue = $('#idOfSelect option:last-child').val();


Can u figure out why ur code is not working...
In case of ur code i m getting undefined..

Comment: @piemesons: Don't know, works for me... But I realize that `:last-child` might be indeed better.

Answer (score 3):

One more way of doing this

```
   $('select option').last().val()
```

or for list

```
   $('ul li').last().text()
```

While above 2 suggestions are perfectly valid, I feel this approach is cleaner than modifying the selector.

Offcourse you should add id/class of specific select/ul if you want to target the particular menu/list.

Comment: This will select all the elements, then create another list containing the last element - hence having last as part of the selector is marginally more efficient.

Comment: @JamesWestgate My suggestion was made to avoid psuedo selector :last-child as these are slower. Also I made edit suggesting to use id/class to target specific menu/list if that is the goal. Thanks.

Comment: :last-child is a css3 selector, so it would be better imho to put that in one selector? That will get passed straight over to QuerySelectorAll and the browser will deal with it, rather than making two separate queries and lists of elements ...

Answer (score 1):

Using attributte selected.

```
$('#SelectName option:last-child').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#id_of_select option:last-of-type').click();`

OR

`$('#id_of_select option:last-child').click();`

Both of these should find and click on the last option on any dynamic drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `selectedIndex` property of plain vanilla JavaScript:

```js
const theSelect = document.getElementById('idOfSelect');
const lastValue = theSelect.selectedIndex = theSelect.options.length - 1;
```