# Resolve the previous selected value of a drop downlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can i get the previous SELECTED value of the drop down list in **javascript or jQuery**, when I change the value of drop down list.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" ....>
```

I am dynamically populating this drop down list.

Comment: The following links will help you to sort it out.

[Link 1][1]

[Link 2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470249/get-value-of-last-option-of-a-drop-down
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470249/get-value-of-last-option-of-a-drop-down

Comment: The list gives the last value...I want the last selected value when I change the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `click` handler and a `change` handler to capture both:

```
var old;
var newV;

$("#<%= ddlList.ClientID %>").click(function() {
    old = this.value;
});

$("#<%= ddlList.ClientID %>").change(function() {
    newV = this.value;
    console.log(newV);
    console.log(old);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/ZG8cN/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but you could attach a click handler to the drop down. When the drop down is clicked, store the current value in a variable. Then in your drop down change function you reference that variable as the previously selected value.

Edit: See @tymeJV example.

Comment: I didn't have time to write any so thought the idea was better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can see is to store the initial value on page load in a Javascript variable, and then keep track of the old value as the selection changes:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ddlTest_prevValue = "<%=ddlTest.SelectedValue %>";
            $("#<%=ddlTest.ClientID%>").change(function () {
                $("#prevValTxt").text("Previous value: " + ddlTest_prevValue);
                ddlTest_prevValue = $("#<%=ddlTest.ClientID%>").val();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server" Width="100" />
    <div id="prevValTxt"></div>
</asp:Content>
```